# Firestore (Flutter) .orderBy Function sorting alphanumerically, sort numerically instead

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a number set for document ids and are sorting based on them: here is a snippet of my code

```dart
StreamBuilder(
   stream: Firestore.instance
      .collection('parties')
      .document(partyCode)
      .collection('guestPicks')
      .orderBy(FieldPath.documentId)
      .snapshots(),
    ...
)
```

when i use this method, it sorts the documents like the following:

```
1
10
11
12
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Can I change this to sort numerically so it's `12345...10 11 12`?
I have other systems depending on this database architecture so changing it has to be a last-ditch  option

Comment: I think you document-id is String. You will need to have another field of int type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore document IDs are always strings.  They can't be treated as numbers.  As such, they will always sort [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) (by string value) as you are currently seeing.

If you want a numeric sort, you will need to add a number type field in your documents, and sort on that field instead of the document ID.